# Sudoko grid conversion from 9*9 to all grid size

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have coded for Sudoku puzzle in Java. The thing is my code has limitation for giving inputs for 9*9 grid. How do I make my code adaptable for all the grids. Please have patience. I am new to java.

What changes do I need to make so that the code can run on all grid sizes?The grid is square not a rectangle.

```
class Solution {
    public void solveSudoku(char[][] board) {
        if(solveSudoku2(board)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    public boolean solveSudoku2(char[][] board) {
        boolean isEmpty = true;
        int row = -1;
        int col = -1;
        int n = board.length;

        //this code is used to check if there exists any empty cell in sudoku board
        //if there is any empty cell, that means we are not done yet and we need to solve it further,
        // so we cannot return true at any point until all the cells are full
        //by empty cell, I mean cells having '.' as the value
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
               if(board[i][j] == '.') {
                   row = i;
                   col = j;
                   isEmpty = false;
                   break;
               }
            }
            if(!isEmpty) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isEmpty) {
            return true;
        }

        //loop for all the numbers and start placing in the empty cells
        //numbers start from 1 to n

        for(int num = 1; num <= n; num++) {
            //convert number to char
            char char_num = (char)(num + '0');
            //check if the number we are adding satisfies all the sudoku rules,
            // if it does, then we place that number in the cell
            if(checkSafe(board,char_num,row,col)) {
                board[row][col] = (char)(num + '0');

                //using this number in place row,col, we check for all the other empty places and see if the board is returning true or not
                // if the board is not filled that means that we need to use other number in row,col place.
                //hence backtrack.
                if(solveSudoku2(board)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    board[row][col] = '.';
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean checkSafe(char[][] board, char num, int row, int col) {
        //checkk if num is present in the row
        for(int i = 0; i< board.length; i++ ) {
            if(board[row][i] == num) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++) {
            if(board[j][col] == num) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        int checknum = (int)Math.sqrt(board.length);
        //check for the current grid. grid will be basically checknum*checknum matrix. where every matrix will start from startrow to  startrow + checknum having checknum length.
        // so, we we have row = 0, then matrix will start from 0 to 2, i.e. the first 3x3 matrix.
        // however, we have row = 2, then also the matrix will start from 0 to 2 - the first 3x3 matrix.
        //however, if row = 3, then we will start our matrix from 3 and cotinute upto 5.

        int startrow = row - row % checknum;
        int startcol = col - col % checknum;
        for(int k = startrow; k < startrow + checknum; k++) {
            for(int l = startcol; l < startcol + checknum; l++) {
                if(board[k][l] == num) {
                    return false;
                }   
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm works by finding the first empty cell, putting the first available number in that cell, and then recursively trying to solve the rest of the board assuming that number is correct, before trying the next number. Is that how you play Sudoku? :-)

Comment: That aside. You're using the characters '1' through '9' on the 9x9 board. What do you want to use as the 10th value for the 10x10 board?

Comment: Is a 10x10 board even possible? It probably has to be a multiple of 3, right?

Comment: Actually, not a multiple of 3. It has to be a number that's a perfect square. So 9, 16, 25, 36, etc., but not 10 or 12.

Comment: One could use NxN and N symbols easily, . . . 11, 12, 13 . . . but the data type is probably going to need re-thinking.

Comment: It's the brute-force exponential approach. It's a great start.

Comment: yes,it is for 9,16,25 etc